# How to visually highlight / catch unnecessary DOM changes in Angular2 app

Tags: angular, dom

I recently saw the video from Google I/O'17 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCMbSyngXB4 and at 11:30 - 11:40 presenter make some click and after each of them automatically highlights dom elements that are changed with a nice green border and background.

Does some body know some chrome plugin, tool or code snippet that can help me do the same for my Angular2 app? Desirable for the whole app at once (not by adding something to each component)

I want this for performance optimization purpose to easily catch unnecessary DOM changes with my eye. 
That could happen because of some forgotten impure pipe for example.

Comment: If you open Chrome dev tools, it shows you what changed by highlighting that (purple). Maybe that could be of help in this matter. Also, in this Tweet, the reactions discuss different options: https://twitter.com/addyosmani/status/537629406785589248?lang=nl

Comment: Yes, I know that, thanks. But it's not really convenient - dom trees could be huge and it's harder to sort out what is really happened - necessary change or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know one chrome feature which looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it seems that what I'm exactly looking for

Answer (score 0):

Chrome DevTools let you see rectangular regions that are *re-rendered*, but I wanted to see particular DOM nodes that are being *changed*, which is more useful for optimising DOM-based code, so I made a tool for that.

It's called [DOM Update Highlighter](https://dom-up.date)

It lets one easily notice excessive rebuilds: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEoiN.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).